# Catch event when remove user control from panel

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I wrote a user control. I have a panel, when I click on the button in user control it is added to the panel. I have created a click event for user control. When clicked, the user control is removed from the panel. I want to ask that to catch the event when the user control is removed, which event should I use and use for panel or user control. For example, I add a label, when adding user control the label will change, and when deleting, the label will also change.
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

The event you are most likely to find helpful is the [`ControlRemoved`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlremoved) event of the `Control`.

This is described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlremoved) thus:

> Occurs when a control is removed from the Control.ControlCollection.

In the case of your example, you would add an event handler for this to the `Panel`.  Assuming your panel is named `panel1` (please don't name it that) this would be something like this:

```
// In initialisation code somewhere
panel1.ControlRemoved += panel1_ControlRemoved;

private void panel1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
    ...
    // Note: removed control is referenced by e.Control
}
```

This would be raised anytime a control is removed from the `Panel`.

There's also an accompanying event for when a control is added which is named [`ControlAdded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controladded).

Comment: thanks, it worked. I also tried using controlremove initially, but it's in user control so it doesn't catch the event

Comment: @HiếuPhạm If it worked, can you please mark this as the answer then?  Also upvote any useful answers too